# Data Frame: Conditionally compare specific value to all values of other column and store resulting vector in list column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to run some simulations on a model (simplified `lm(col_B ~ col_A)`)for which I would like to define new x-values sampled from the old x-values and based on several conditions. For each of my species (1-20) I would like to generate a vector containing *all* values of col_B (independent of the species) if they follow a certain condition. From those vectors, I want to later sample one single value as a "new" col_B value to use as x-value. I can easily do this by defining all those vectors seperately:

```
# make up example data
dat <- data.frame("species" =  seq(1:20), "col_A" = runif(20, min=1000, max=2500), "col_B" = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1500), "maximum" = rep(2500, 20))

# define vectors for all species
possible_1 <- dat$col_A[dat$col_A <= max(dat$maximum)-dat$col_B[1]]
possible_2 <- dat$col_A[dat$col_A <= max(dat$maximum)-dat$col_B[2]]
possible_3 <- dat$col_A[dat$col_A <= max(dat$maximum)-dat$col_B[3]]

# etc.
```

Of course I could also come up with a loop and store the vectors in a new data frame etc. However, I was thinking whether it would be possible to store those vectors in a list column in my original data frame to sample from them later and keep everything within `dplyr` and a nice pipe line. Additionally, for creating the vectors I need to compare the col_B value of a specific species to all col_A values of all species - which I don't know how to. So my questions are:

1. How to create a list column containing a vector of different length for all species?
2. Is it possible to compare a specific value from one column to all values of another column?

Desired output:

```
dat_end <- structure(list(species = 1:20, col_A = c(1201.07331767213, 1248.07284446433, 
1721.88013594132, 1811.97518436238, 1957.70114450715, 2003.58936993871, 
2017.67337811179, 1835.36564861424, 1297.55500191823, 2309.16906765196, 
1811.72096473165, 1041.0662824288, 1890.41095413268, 2180.55545398965, 
2254.29310277104, 2146.93792897742, 1086.34597295895, 1633.36910132784, 
2027.77895331383, 1044.20079500414), col_B = c(1316.56480673701, 
698.999502696097, 486.406950862147, 362.3069843743, 774.72961822059, 
5.33419672865421, 261.744535993785, 252.763583441265, 1466.9924180489, 
926.854150719009, 28.8207863923162, 1203.98436568212, 669.935327139683, 
1270.13235166669, 1010.53655776195, 649.534532683901, 1407.57358598057, 
1376.92801596131, 701.711902976967, 783.507982618175), maximum = c(2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500), vector_column = c("vector_1", 
"vector_2", "vector_3", "vector_4", "vector_5", "vector_6", "vector_7", 
"vector_8", "vector_9", "vector_10", "vector_11", "vector_12", 
"vector_13", "vector_14", "vector_15", "vector_16", "vector_17", 
"vector_18", "vector_19", "vector_20"), col_B_new = c("sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", "sample(vector_column, 1)", 
"sample(vector_column, 1)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_end <- dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(vector_column = list(dat$col_A[dat$col_A <= maximum - col_B]), # using list function to store vectors in a data.frame
         helper = !is_empty(vector_column), # some of the vectors are empty so it is not possible to use sample
         col_B_new = ifelse(helper, sample(vector_column, 1), NA),
         helper = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

As for question 1, see if the following is what you want.

```
possible <- lapply(dat$col_B, function(B) {
  dat$col_A[dat$col_A <= max(dat$maximum) - B]
})

head(possible)
#[[1]]
# [1] 1970.354 1591.339 1927.753 1715.337 1204.146 1101.077 1193.729
# [8] 1589.677 1003.874 1930.309 2146.621 2115.754 1634.094 1613.931
#[15] 1809.539 1980.336 1820.073 1399.095
#
#[[2]]
# [1] 1970.354 1591.339 1927.753 1715.337 1204.146 1101.077 1193.729
# [8] 1589.677 1003.874 1930.309 2146.621 2115.754 2239.249 1634.094
#[15] 1613.931 1809.539 1980.336 1820.073 1399.095
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1204.146 1101.077 1193.729 1003.874
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1003.874
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 1101.077 1003.874
#
#[[6]]
# [1] 1970.354 1591.339 1927.753 1715.337 1204.146 1101.077 1193.729
# [8] 1589.677 1003.874 1930.309 2146.621 2115.754 2239.249 1634.094
#[15] 1613.931 1809.539 1980.336 1820.073 1399.095
```

As for question 2, the answer is yes, it is possible. In fact, the code above compares `dat$col_A` with each of `max(dat$maximum) - dat$col_B[1]`, `max(dat$maximum) - dat$col_B[2]`, etc.

**Data**

```
set.seed(2020)
dat <- data.frame("species" =  1:20, "col_A" = runif(20, min=1000, max=2500), "col_B" = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1500), "maximum" = rep(2500, 20))
```

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. OP's possible_two returns a vector of length 2 whilst yours whilst yours [[2]] is of the length 19.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was looking specifically for a dplyr solution and a way to add the vectors directly to my original data frame.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny That's true but I had forgot to include the *reproducible* data creation code, I have now updated it and set the RNG seed.